# warning: declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration

Tags: c

My Compiler(gcc) is showing the warning

> warning: declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration

Please help me understand why this warning comes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's when you do something like:

```
int index;
int main (void) {
    int index;
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

What it's warning about is that the `index` inside `main()` is actually *hiding* the global one you've declared before `main()`.

It's warning you that you can't get at the global definition while the local one is "active". Now that's not *necessarily* a problem (hence why it's only a warning), it's perfectly valid C, but you need to be aware of the possible consequences.

> As an aside, some C implementations (BSD-based) define an `index` *function* in `string.h` which may also cause a problem. Use of this function is deprecated and it doesn't appear in the C standard (use `strchr` instead) but it may be the cause of problems if you're running on (for example) Mac OS or OpenBSD (or even Linux under some combination of `#define` settings, I believe).

There are a couple of ways to get around this (if you need to).

The first is probably the preferred one: don't *use* globals. Yes, that's right, get rid of them. They're very rarely needed so don't make me come over and slap you around :-)

A second way I've seen is to ensure they're "packaged". Assuming that you actually *need* globals (by no means a certainty, see previous paragraph), create a structure that holds them, such as in the following:

```
myglobs.h:
    struct sMyGlobs {
        int index;
        // all other globals.
    };
    extern struct sMyGlobs myGlobs;

myglobs.c:
    #include "myglobs.h"
    struct sMyGlobs myGlobs;

main.c:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "myglobs.h"
    int main (void) {
        myGlobs.index = 42;
        return 0;
    }
```

This has the advantage in that it's obvious that you're referring to a global and that they're never hidden, unless you do something like define your own local variable called `myGlobs`.

Comment: I often use globals as state information (aggregated together in a config structure) when writing hardware drivers (e.g. the latest configuration of the hardware since the API was last used). It is often advantageous/necessary to cache this information in this type of situation. Over the years I have heard countless arguments for _not_ using globals, but what are some other `valid` use-cases of as you see it?

Comment: For example, see [here](https://github.com/sherrellbc/mock-OS/blob/periph_cmos_dev/mock/kernel/arch/i386/irq/irq_core/pic8259.c#L119-L123) or [here](https://github.com/sherrellbc/mock-OS/blob/periph_cmos_dev/mock/kernel/arch/i386/irq/cmos/cmos.c#L134-L138) and [here](https://github.com/sherrellbc/mock-OS/blob/periph_cmos_dev/mock/kernel/arch/i386/irq/cmos/cmos.c#L115-L121). They remain a work in progress. In this case I needed state information for use in an asynchronous interrupt handler. Arguably something like this can't be done _without_ globals. It depends on context, as always.