# How to suppress shadow "index" warning?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, string.h

I maintain a cross-platform C codebase and on a few platforms (Xcode 4, Red Hat derived distros like Fedora and Mageia), I get the following compiler error:

```
warning: declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8440993/2038264), I understand that this is because some BSD-based C implementations define a non-standard `index` function in `string.h` which means that this warning shows up whenever I declare an `index` variable. I assure you that I do not have any global `index` variables.

I know I can avoid naming anything `index` but it's a semantically useful name so I end up using it all over the place. I know I can also suppress this warning, for example by using `-Wno-shadow` in GCC, but I'd rather not globally disable an otherwise useful compiler warning.

So how can I solve this problem? That is, is it somehow possible to detect if the platform has the `index` function and disable the warning there only, or how can I redefine it if it exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a GCC bug [fixed in 4.8 branch](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html)

> The option -Wshadow no longer warns if a declaration shadows a function declaration, unless the former declares a function or pointer to function, because this is a common and valid case in real-world code.

This is no longer a problem in Mageia 4 (GCC 4.8.2) or Fedora 19 (GCC 4.8.1) and 20 (GCC 4.8.2) but I don't know any clean solution to avoid the warning apart from changing the variable name, maybe to something more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Check the header where `index` is declared, it may be wrapped in some `#if` or `#ifdef` that you may exploit to prevent it from being declared.

There may also be a compiler `#pragma` that you can use to disable the warning on the specific line it occurs. At least `clang` has this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow"
// code that produces warning
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

I think `gcc` has the same if you replace `clang` with `GCC`. Older versions may not support `push`, and I'm not sure if the switch for the warning is the same in both. If it works with `#pragma GCC`, `clang` should also recognise the `#pragma` so you don't need to duplicate.

For the record, I don't get this warning by including `<string.h>` and defining `int index;` on either Debian or OS X with `clang` or `gcc` using `-Wshadow`… Are you sure your `index` comes from `<string.h>`? On OS X with XCode 5 it is in `<strings.h>` (plural).

Comment: I no longer get it in OSX since Xcode 5 I believe. I also have not seen it in Debian-based Linuxes.