# Problems with empty variables

Tags: c

i have a problem in function normally it's return the key pressed on the keybord so it returns a char this hat i have written :

```
void Get ( char ch)
{       
        printf("choisir le touche que vous convient : /n ");
        ch=fgetc(stdin);
        printf("%c is pressed ",ch);
        scanf ("%c" , &ch);
        printf("%c is pressed ",ch);
}
```

and the ch , global variable , was declared as a static char .

```
static char ch ;
int main ()
{   Get(ch) ;
    printf ("%c" , ch ) ;
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '1':
        printf ( "1 ");
        break ; 
    case '2':
        printf ( "2 ");
        break ; 
 }
```

the problem is when i call this function the value is always NULL
Can anyone help me

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve].

Comment: BTW: don't confuse slash and backslash.

Comment: The `ch` shown in your code is neither global nor static; it's the function argument.

Comment: Also remember that the `scanf` format `%c` will read white-space, like the newline left over from the `Enter` key you probably pressed for the `fgetc` call.

Comment: Furthermore remember that global variables are *zero* initialized. C doesn't have the concept of "null values". And that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) really returns an `int`, which is rather important if you need to compare it to the `int` constant `EOF` (which you generally should do).

Comment: It appears you have two objects using the identifier `ch`. One is global, the other is local to the function `Get()`. Any changes to either of them will not be reflected in the other.

Comment: Lastly, please learn how to use a *debugger* to step through code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: If you want a function to be able to modify a variable specified by the caller, then you need to pass its address.

Comment: Until you understand them well, do not mix `fgetc` and `scanf`.  (On a related note, don't use `scanf`!)

Comment: This is a dupe... who find it first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error in c: declaration shadows a variable in the global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238366/error-in-c-declaration-shadows-a-variable-in-the-global-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to what @kadina has posted, you could pass a pointer to a character to your `Get` function.

You also need to eliminate the trailing newline character from your format string.

```
void Get(char *ch) {
    scanf("%c", ch);
}
```

And in main, we declare a variable `ch` of type `char`, since there is no need for global variables, then pass a pointer to that to `Get`.

```
int main(void) {
    char ch;
    Get(&ch);
}
```

Hopefully this helps point you in the right direction.

**Note:** calling `scanf` in this way discards any opportunity to test the return value, and thus to know whether the I/O was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate variables called `ch` -- a local parameter to the `Get` function and a global static `ch`.  The global static is used as the argument to `Get` in `main`, so its value will be used to initialize the parameter `ch`, but other than that, these are two completely separate variables with no connection between them.

So within `Get`, `ch` will refer to the parameter `ch`, and changes to it (by assignment or with `scanf`) will have no effect on the global `ch`